# Parsing and editing XML files with conditions

Tags: java, xml, parsing, editing, xerces

For a small project that I am currently working on, I am required to parse a large number of "settings" files and change values under certain conditions. I *believe* these files are formatted in XML, however I am beginning to doubt this, as I am using Apache's Xerces XML parser to parse the files in java and am getting strange results...

Here is a sample "settings" file that I need to parse (I appoligize in advance for the formatting):

```
<LIBRARY_ITEM><NAME> AUsten(REdsockswhiteandblack), Kevin(Greysocks),
Johnny(REdandwhitesocksTall), David(REdandwhitesocksshort)(10)-Camera 1.avi
</NAME><ID>{DA656F16-CDDE-49C5-83B6-865DFB58356A}</ID><VERSION
subversion="1">2.0</VERSION><THUMBNAIL_INDEX>0</THUMBNAIL_INDEX><CATEGORIES>
<CATEGORY name="Skaters" id="{90a42bf0-58ec-46d4-8a54-8bbf7844d63a}">Johnny
Yaremko</CATEGORY><CATEGORY name="Skills" id="{165e7d21-aa8f-4376-b38b-
6fe20680e0d4}">Drop &amp; Go</CATEGORY></CATEGORIES><CAMERA_NAME_NODE
CAMERA_NAME="Camera 1"/><TYPE>1</TYPE><LIBRARY_ITEM ItemType="Marker" IN="0"
UNIT="RefTime" OUT="0" SynchMarker="yes"><NAME></NAME><ID>{B02BA392-50D4-490C-9FDB-
0B7B350D2281}</ID><VERSION subversion="1">2.0</VERSION><FILE_NAME></FILE_NAME>
<Library.MDProperties><Property Name="Title" DefaultValue=""><![CDATA[Synch Point]]>
</Property></Library.MDProperties><Data Id="ODKeyPosition"><![CDATA[<ODKeyPosition
Version="1.0"><DrawingStream Value="1&#xA;0 13 BEGIN_SCENE_11052 3 0 1 0 65535 0 0 0 0
0 0.84375 0 1 0 1 720 9 END_SCENE"/></ODKeyPosition>]]></Data></LIBRARY_ITEM>
<CAMERA_NAME_NODE CAMERA_NAME="Camera 1"/><Library.MDLibraryItemLink><Reference
Id="TWIN"><LibraryItem Id="{74927B4E-00FF-4E12-B428-BF392E82CFA2}"
LastKnownLocation=".\ AUsten(REdsockswhiteandblack), Kevin(Greysocks),
Johnny(REdandwhitesocksTall), David(REdandwhitesocksshort)(10)-Camera 2.avi"/>
</Reference></Library.MDLibraryItemLink><OverlayDrawing><![CDATA[13 BEGIN_SCENE_11052 3
 0 1 0 65535 0 0 0 0 0 0.84375 0 1 2 13501 3 0 1 0 65520 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 13 1105 3 0 1
 0 65535 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 2 360 0 0 1 360 576 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 255 104 32 255 1 127 127
 127 255 0 3 2 0 20 20 1 1105 3 0 1 0 65535 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 2 420 0 0 1 420 576 0 1 0 0
 0 0 1 2 1 255 104 32 255 1 127 127 127 255 0 3 2 0 20 20 1 1105 3 0 1 0 65535 0 0 0 0
 0 1 0 2 2 480 0 0 1 480 576 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 255 104 32 255 1 127 127 127 255 0 3 2 0
 20 20 1 1105 3 0 1 0 65535 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 2 540 0 0 1 540 576 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 255 
104 32 255 1 127 127 127 255 0 3 2 0 20 20 1 1105 3 0 1 0 65535 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 2 600 0
 0 1 600 576 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 255 104 32 255 1 127 127 127 255 0 3 2 0 20 20 1 1105 3
 0 1 0 65535 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 2 660 0 0 1 660 576 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 255 104 32 255 1 127
 127 127 255 0 3 2 0 20 20 1 1105 3 0 1 0 65535 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 2 720 0 0 1 720 576 0 1
 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 255 104 32 255 1 127 127 127 255 0 3 2 0 20 20 1 1105 3 0 1 0 65535 0 0
 0 0 0 1 0 2 2 300 0 0 1 300 576 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 255 104 32 255 1 127 127 127 255 0 3
 2 0 20 20 1 1105 3 0 1 0 65535 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 2 240 0 0 1 240 576 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1
 255 104 32 255 1 127 127 127 255 0 3 2 0 20 20 1 1105 3 0 1 0 65535 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 2
 180 0 0 1 180 576 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 255 104 32 255 1 127 127 127 255 0 3 2 0 20 20 1 
1105 3 0 1 0 65535 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 2 120 0 0 1 120 576 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 255 104 32 255
 1 127 127 127 255 0 3 2 0 20 20 1 1105 3 0 1 0 65535 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 2 60 0 0 1 60 576
 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 255 104 32 255 1 127 127 127 255 0 3 2 0 20 20 1 1105 3 0 1 0 65535 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 2 0 0 0 1 0 576 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 255 104 32 255 1 127 127 127 255 0 3
 2 0 20 20 1 1 1 3 1 11 lineSpaceId19 Space between lines1 0 60 1 11 gridWidthId10 Grid
 Width1 0 720 1 12 gridHeightId11 Grid Height1 0 576 0 1 1 13 orientationId16 Grid
 Orientation1 0 1 0 0 0 13501 3 0 1 0 65520 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 9 1105 3 0 1 0 65535 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 2 2 0 288 0 1 720 288 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 255 104 32 255 1 127 127 127 255 0 3 2
 0 20 20 1 1105 3 0 1 0 65535 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 2 0 348 0 1 720 348 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 255
 104 32 255 1 127 127 127 255 0 3 2 0 20 20 1 1105 3 0 1 0 65535 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 2 0 
408 0 1 720 408 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 255 104 32 255 1 127 127 127 255 0 3 2 0 20 20 1 1105   
3 0 1 0 65535 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 2 0 468 0 1 720 468 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 255 104 32 255 1    
127 127 127 255 0 3 2 0 20 20 1 1105 3 0 1 0 65535 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 2 0 528 0 1 720 528
 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 255 104 32 255 1 127 127 127 255 0 3 2 0 20 20 1 1105 3 0 1 0 65535
 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 2 0 228 0 1 720 228 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 255 104 32 255 1 127 127 127 255
 0 3 2 0 20 20 1 1105 3 0 1 0 65535 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 2 0 168 0 1 720 168 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2
 1 255 104 32 255 1 127 127 127 255 0 3 2 0 20 20 1 1105 3 0 1 0 65535 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2
 2 0 108 0 1 720 108 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 255 104 32 255 1 127 127 127 255 0 3 2 0 20 20 1
 1105 3 0 1 0 65535 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 2 0 48 0 1 720 48 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 255 104 32 255
 1 127 127 127 255 0 3 2 0 20 20 1 1 1 3 1 11 lineSpaceId19 Space between lines1 0 60 1
 11 gridWidthId10 Grid Width1 0 720 1 12 gridHeightId11 Grid Height1 0 576 0 1 1 13
 orientationId16 Grid Orientation1 0 0 0 0 0 1 720 9 END_SCENE]]></OverlayDrawing>
<Library.MDProperties><Property Name="CameraID" DefaultValue=""><![CDATA[0]]>
</Property><Property Name="Comment" DefaultValue=""><![CDATA[This is an acceleration
 drill. The skater uses a wider stance than normal to achieve a shorter but more rapid
 stride. This is required to get up to full speed in a hurry. Once at full speed a long
 powerful stride will keep you there with the least amount of energy consumed. Body
 position is once again important. Leaning too far forward will cause the skater to 
loose traction as all their weight is not over their skates.]]></Property><Property
 Name="Title" DefaultValue=""><![CDATA[ AUsten(REdsockswhiteandblack),
 Kevin(Greysocks), Johnny(REdandwhitesocksTall), David(REdandwhitesocksshort)(10)-
Camera 1.avi]]></Property></Library.MDProperties></LIBRARY_ITEM>
```

If it helps at all, these files each correspond to an AVI video clip. I am trying to edit many of them at once using a few conditional statements so that the clips properties are changed within the application that references them. This is a third party application, therefore making this task fairly difficult for me as all of the testing must be done "blackbox" (I don't know what method/structure the developers used to write these settings files).

I guess I am asking whether this data conforms to XML standards, or if it is an entirely different structure. There are a few spots in these files that don't look like proper XML...

[UPDATE] Here is the code I am using to scan through the parsed data and print it to screen (to make sure everything is structured properly):

```
public Analyzer(String source) {

    DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();

    int level= 0;
    Node curItem = null;

    try {
        parser.parse(source);
        Document doc = parser.getDocument();

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("LIBRARY_ITEM");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            read(nodeList.item(i), 0);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void read(Node node, int level) {

    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }

    int type = node.getNodeType();
    switch (type) {
        case Node.DOCUMENT_NODE: {
            System.out.print(node.getNodeName()+": ");
            read(((Document) node).getDocumentElement(), level+1);
            break;
        }


        case Node.TEXT_NODE: {
            System.out.print(" = \""+node.getNodeValue().replaceAll("\\s", "")+"\"");
            break;
        }

        case Node.ELEMENT_NODE: {
            System.out.print("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
            System.out.print(node.getNodeName());
            NodeList children = node.getChildNodes();
            int length = children.getLength();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                read(children.item(i), level+1);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

When it runs, it does some funky things to a few of the fields... Also, some of the values are not printed correctly. This could easily be my mistake, as I am **very** inexperienced with XML.

Comment: the xml parser in my eyes thinks that this is valid xml.  you shouldn't be using xerces directly, just use the stuff built into the jdk.  what do you mean by "strange results"?  does it parse w/out error?

Comment: SO I should be loading the Xerces parser into Java's built in handling classes (like the cryptography classes)?

It compiles and parses without error, however some of the nodes seem to be missing... This is my first real exercise with XML so I may be  doing something wrong. Should I post the code I'm using to print out the data?

Comment: edited question with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you still haven't completely described your prolbem (i.e. i don't know what "funky" means in terms of incorrect output).  that said, you mention missing data, and the xml has CDATA sections, so i would imagine your code is missing a case for CDATA nodes, e.g. `Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE`.

also be aware that there may be *multiple* child text nodes for a given element node (the xml parser is allowed to break them up while parsing).

Comment: Ahh! I was unaware CDATA nodes existed! This was one of the main reasons I thought that this file may infact not be proper XML... What exactly is the purpose of a CDATA node?

Comment: @araisbec - it's a hack which allows you to manually write xml more easily (it allows certain characters which are disallowed in normal xml text).  ultimately, it serves no purpose... :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; your answer pointed me in the right direction. I was using someone elses code snippet to parse the XML tree, and I was ignoring attributes and CDATA nodes. I updated the code to include these types of nodes and was successful in achieving my desired result. In my case, the CDATA nodes were very important to what I was trying to do; They stored "Comment" data from the application I was working with, which I was required to modify. Thank you for your help, I now have a fairly good understanding of XML.